# windows 10, apps install with other language than my windows language

Tags: windows-10, language

I have a Spanish notebook, but during Windows setup i chose english language and in my settings
i set UK as a region, and UK regional format.
But when i install some apps, they install in Spanish language (without asking me or my consent).
Which setting apps use to recognise the user language, and why are they do it wrong?

Which setting is responsible for that behaviour ?

Which setting is responsible for that behaviour ?
I thought that maybe my problem is with 'region' set to Spain, but after changing it to UK, some new apps still install with default Spanish (and not English) ....

Comment: That depends on the app and how it detects what language to use. Before Windows 7 the user language was always the system language, therefore if the app just uses the (default) system language you may end up with Spanish.

Comment: i know it depends on app, but apps uses some Windows settings to determine language - and they did that WRONG,  my question is, is there one setting that determine that? or many different and apps do whatever they want (of course developers can do whatever they want).  and at the end there is a mess, and wrong guessing anyway ...

Comment: The standard system language is determined by the installation media you use. I am not sure if this can be changed later. If an app determines the wrong language than this is a bug and you should contact the app author/developer(s) so that this bug can be corrected.

Comment: @Robert - It can indeed be changed.

Comment: @Ramhound But AFAIK WIndows still "remembers" what installation media was used. Or do you know how to change the value for the default UI language returned by `dism /online /get-intl`?

Comment: @Robert - You can change the language the current or default user will use by default.  I don't know or choose to know about `/get-intl`